# How to display iframe in lightning by direct-loading content (without a src: url)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have read [Is it possible to add iFrame directly in Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166612/is-it-posible-to-add-iframe-directly-in-lightning-components), this is not a duplicate.  I need to display an iframe, but I cannot supply a `src` url.

Briefly, I need to display `EmailMessage.htmlBody` within my component, but the emails are coming from Outlook (via 3rd party syncing tool), so the email content includes `html`, `head`, and `style` tags.  The client wants to keep the formatting, so I don't want to strip out the `style`. Both `lightning:formattedRichText` and `ui:outputRichText` strip out a number of tags including `html`, `head`, and `style`.  Further, the way they strip them out leaves some of the `xmlns:xxx` attributes from the `html` tag present in the display, so they won't work.

I've looked at how the OOB EmailMessage view page in LEX works, and it's showing the email body inside an iframe... complete with all of the outlook-generated tags inside the iframe.  But, there's no `src` tag on the iframe, so I assume they are loading the iframe from JS.

I've tried the following:

1. Direct setting, e.g., `iframe[0].contentDocument.write(html)`.  The wrapper object api doesn't expose contentDocument.
2. `data:` url, with the email body base64 encoded.  CSP restriction doesn't allow Data urls.  The CSP settings in SF allow for additional urls, but do not support the `data:` scheme (per the error message when I tried).
3. `blob:` url, creating the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) in js using the email body.  No CSP error, and if I debug the `blob:` url and paste it in the browser, I see the email body.  But when I set it in the iframe in the page, I get a blank iframe.  Inspecting the iframe content in chrome dev tools shows a simple empty html doc that isn't the content I put in my `blob:` url.

So I'm stuck.  How can I render the full html which I have as an object property, but not as an url, inside an iframe, in a Ltng Component?

Comment: Have you tried [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml/specification)?

Comment: Is srcdoc exposed? *goes to check*

Comment: The 'srcdoc' attribute is not supported for 'iframe' - that's a no

Comment: @JasonClark sure thing. One moment.

Comment: I am also looking for same thing, but aura:unescapedHtml breaks the page like picaso sometime, on most of times its working fine but it breaks on few occasions. Can you tell me workaround for this, please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml) to inject almost any kind of HTML. As usual in this case, make sure that you trust the source code to avoid injection attacks, or at least do some minimal scrubbing of potentially dangerous tags.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and eliminated the need for the iframe.  Looking at the rendered html, it has automatically removed the `html`, `head`, and `body` tags, and moved the `meta` and `style` tags from `head` into the rendered content - `style` being the important bit for my use case.

Comment: @JasonClark could you post sample code in a fiddle? I am attempting the same test and would appreciate it.

Comment: @Geo Not sure I could make a working fiddle with aura code, but it's literally just `<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.note.body}" />`, where `note.body` is a string loaded directly from a RichText sobject field.  I stuck that tag inside a `div` with `display: block;` styling and was done.

Comment: Very nice solution; however, the lightening styling might overwrite the styling of whatever is places in "aura:unescapedHtml". Is there any solution to prevent lightning from overwriting aura:unescapedHtml style?

Comment: @Cubancoffee I didn't run into an issue with lightning styles affecting my rendered html, but if you do, I'd try adding "css reset" styles (a set of CSS rules meant to clear or "reset" browser styles), plus whatever styles you want to use, to the div containing the `aura:unescapedHtml` component.  A quick google search will show you some options for CSS reset styles.  You may need to tweak a bit to undo specific SLDS styles that aren't accounted for by a CSS Reset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind an aura attribute to the source of the iframe.
When the attribute change, so the iframe source.

```
<aura:attribute name="vfHost"           type="String" default="" />

<iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{! v.vfHost }"/>
```

Although, if you have the content of the email in a JS var, why do you need to put it in an iframe. You can render inside a lighting component in a DIV

```
<div id="divEmailText"></div>

renderHTML : function(strHTML) { 
 document.getElementById('divEmailText').innerHTML = strHTML; 
}
```

Comment: I couldn't bind to src as I don't have an url for the email body, just a property from my model object.  And I wanted the iframe so that I wouldn't have to modify the html body (remove html, head, body tags, move style tag into the rendered output) before rendering.